# What is Blender's maximum render size?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

What is Blender's maximum render (not scene) size? Like in either MegaPixels or a pixel length x width dimension. On my side it seems to be locked at 22000 pixels. Using the Cycles render engine to render TIFFs.

Thanks
JK

Comment: Just for me to know - for what type of practice do you need images in that size? As HDR Background? or for printing purposes? I did renders for printing in 7000x5000 px until now.

Comment: I personally rendered ~ 30x10k for film work. The task was to render with resolution enought to do close up shot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The maximum render size is computer dependent, and therefore also scene dependent. In Cycles, it is further constrained by GPU RAM if you are using GPU rendering; my experience is that my Titan X is fast, but easy to overwhelm. Note that having multiple GPU cards makes rendering faster, but each card must still be able to get the image into GPU RAM (as I understand it based on StackExchange info).

We sometimes render images bigger than 30K in one or both dimensions. The easiest way to do so is certainly to send off your image to a farm that supports tiling. Your images will be broken into segments and rendered individually, then recomposited. Depending upon the farm, some features (compositor, render border) may be disabled, and this approach is less useful with some global illumination schemes.

I suspect a python ninja could create a plug-in to do this, allowing the same approach on your desktop... although another advantage of a farm is that you do not have to sit through a 1.5 billion pixel render.

FYI: http://archive.vcstar.com/news/special/outdoors/lookout-tower-gives-glimpse-underwater-as-channel-islands-park-turns-35-ep-972578364-348067821.html

That is one of two wall images, each more than 50 feet tall. Done in Blender (although in multiple scene files).

Comment: https://kevinlorengel.gumroad.com/l/SuperResRender - this add-on does exactly the same! It is free!
Huge thanks to Kevin Lorengel

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it is locked to 22000. I have personally rendered image 43000 + pixels in one dimension.

Biggest picture i rendered was around 30000x10000. All those was in multi layer EXR and .png

The bigger problem i found is saving those images. Blender crashed on me when i saved images this large. I have to render it in parts and compose whole image after.

Comment: I just tested this, and with an empty scene and a 20K*10K render, Blender memory usage goes from 800MB to >9GB when saving to PNG with default settings. Everything was locked until paging ended.

Comment: And imagine you saving a multi layer EXR with channels for depth, diffuse, glossy, etc. I lost quite alot of time before i rendered all the stuff by parts using render regions. It was not possible to save the whole image, Blender rendered it, but was not able to save it after. And it was on machine with 32 cores and 64+ GIG's or RAM.

Answer (score 3):

The maximum rendered image size will depend on how much RAM you have, with the scene size adding to the RAM needed.

Up to v2.66 you can enter a resolution up to a maximum size of 10,000 in both directions and from v2.67 that increased to 65,536 and you can then multiply that with a scale up to 32,767% which leads to a maximum of 21,474,181 in either direction (or 3,270,000 before 2.67).

Given a resolution of 65536x65536x100% blender allocates 98G. While it tries to start rendering I don't have enough RAM for it to get far in any reasonable amount of time.