# Blender's video export options?

Tags: export, video, frame-rate, resolution

I'm relatively new to Blender, and am considering downloading it to edit videos. Currently, I use WeVideo, but it only supports exports of 25 fps and 720p, which isn't very good for the types of videos that I plan on creating. So I am wondering, what is the max resolution and FPS for exports that Blender can support?

**Update:** This question seems like a duplicate of [another question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67193/31410). However, this doesn't answer my question because it only states the maximum size, in pixels, of a render. None of the answers provided mention anything about frames per second, and revolves around file size, not exports.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is Blender's maximum render size?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67193/what-is-blenders-maximum-render-size)

Comment: @Emir No, it is not a duplicate. See the update in the post.

Comment: Blender will render at any frame rate supported by the output media, which pretty much means any frame rate.  It also renders to a wide range of file outputs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short version is that Blender can output nearly any frame rate and video format you would likely want.  The long answer follows.

There are 3 parts to the answer for your question.

1. As https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/66870/emir mentioned, this question answers you about what size the image frame can be:  [What is Blender's maximum render size?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67193/what-is-blenders-maximum-render-size)
2. The Frame rate is set in the property editor's Scene dimension's menu:

[image: scene dimension's menu]

All of the 'industry standard' frame rates are supported:

[image: industry standard frame rates]

and you can use the bottom item in the menu to set a custom frame rate.

3. The output format is selected in the properties editor Scene Output Menu:

[image: scene output menu]

and you can select from a wide range of still formats or video container formats:

[image: output image formats]

The usual approach is to render to a series of still images, most often png although openEXR is becoming popular and then to use the visual sequence editor to assemble the images.  Once that's done, you render the output one more time, switching to one of the 3 movie formats.  Each movie format also has options for output codecs.  For instance if I select 'FFmpeg Video', new options appear:

[image: FFmpeg encoding options]

How well Blender will suit your editing needs depends a great deal on how much memory you have on your computer, of course.

Answer (score 3):

There are virtually no limits to export settings, except thoose of the desired codecs and containers, but the video editing user interface is not efficient as many others softwares can offer, and the playback isn't optimized so well.

Video editing is not the strongest point of Blender, I suggest to check free version of DaVinci Resolve, if 1920 x 1080 is enough for you.

Besides, Blender is very good at converting video files format.

Answer (score 1):

You are able to edit the fps of the video, but be in mind that if you are animating something you need to sorta 'match' the fps, iirc the set fps is 24.

If you want 3 seconds of animation at 60 fps you'll need 180 frames etc. The sky is the limit when it comes to exports, although you do have to change the resolution manually. Its defaulted at 1080p (1920x1080).